# PHP Unit Testing Coverage

Tags: php, code-coverage

I'm new to PHP development but have experience developing Python web applications.  In Python, there is a package called [Coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) that analyzes the code and identifies functionality that is missing Unit Tests.

Does such a package exist in the PHP world?  I have searched Google and SO and come up short.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 14):

PHPUnit has coverage built in. You can generate a html coverage report by using

```
phpunit --coverage-html /[path where to save report]
```

Another option is `--coverage-clover` instead of `--coverage-html`. That will generate an xml report about what is covered.

If you use an advanced IDE like phpStorm you can just right click on the test and select "Run with coverage", it will display the coverage in the editor's file explorer.

Comment: For the terminal just run `phpunit --coverage-text`.

Answer (score 4):

PHPUnit itself has the coverage tool which uses [PHP_CodeCoverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage)

This page shows all the different coverage options: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html

An example html output coverage command line would be:

```
phpunit ./report tests/*
```

This will create a folder called report and contain all the coverage for all the tests under tests/ folder

Answer (score 3):

PHPUnit supports code coverage and is the de facto standard. Integrates with Jenkins et al.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes There are number of code coverage tools.
Add below linkes to your phpunit.xml

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./mainreport" charset="UTF-8"
         yui="true" highlight="true"
         lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
</logging>
```

install XDEBUG , `(ex: for ubuntu and php7 - sudo apt-get install php7.0-xdebug)`

This will log your report to the directory specified in target attribute (target="./mainreport"). Also the report will be in html format

create a `mainreport` directory in your root . 
run the unit test
open index.html in browser and you can see coverage report .

Comment: <log type="coverage-html" target="./mainreport" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" /> Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Also you can generate Cases Report by checking how many cases are pass or fail in your project module Wise using json file.

Add this code into your phpnit.xml file :

```
<log type="json" target="./log/jsonreport.json" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

After run, generated file (`jsonreport.json`) of passed case list should exist.